# Single Azure Mobile Service, multiple OS

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm new to Azure and are trying to understand the various services, and currently i'm trying to understand the Mobile Service, and it's various features, such as authentication and push.

Does a Mobile Service only support one app on one OS, or is it possible to use the same service for multiple apps across multiple OS's (Android, iOS and Win Mobile)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same service for multiple platforms. For example, if you create a new mobile service, and go to the quickstart tab in the Azure portal, you can download a sample application for 5 platforms (Windows Store, Windows Phone, iOS, Android, HTML/JS). The apps will run in different platforms, but they will all be backed up by the same service, so if you insert an item in the app on one platform and refresh the app on another, you'll see the item there.